# How do I loop over dictionary and check for values passed by a variable in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I've got the below dictionary and list - how do I loop over the dictionary checking if `b == '1'` while passing `'1'` as variable from a list?

```
dic = {'info': [{'a':0, 'b':'1'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'1'}]}

lst = ['1']
```

I want to return `{'a':0, 'b':'1'}, {'a':0, 'b':'1'}`.

Comment: Will the list always have exactly one item? Will this item(s) always be a value of key `b`? Is the expected output supposed to be a list or a tuple? Will `info` always be the only key on the dictionary `dic`? If the answer to all those questions is yes then the answer by Kasramvd is as good as it gets.

Comment: I wonder why it's downvoted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general solution using `filter`; the built-in method, you will have to adopt it to your needs:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda d: d['b'] in lst, dic['info']))
[{'b': '1', 'a': 0}, {'b': '1', 'a': 0}]
```

Converting the `filter` object into a list using `list` constructor is necessary only in Python3, whereas in Python2, it is not required:

```
>>> filter(lambda d: d['b'] in lst, dic['info'])
[{'b': '1', 'a': 0}, {'b': '1', 'a': 0}]
```

EDIT: To make the solution more general in case multiple items in `lst`, then consider the following:

```
>>> dic
{'info': [{'b': '1', 'a': 0}, {'b': '3', 'a': 0}, {'b': '3', 'a': 0}, {'b': '1', 'a': 0}, {'b': '2', 'a': '1'}]}
>>>
>>> lst
['1', '2']
>>> def filter_dict(dic_lst, lst):
        lst_out = []
        for sub_d in dic_lst:
            if any(x == sub_d['b'] for x in lst):
                lst_out.append(sub_d)
        return lst_out

>>> filter_dict(dic['info'], lst)
[{'b': '1', 'a': 0}, {'b': '1', 'a': 0}, {'b': '2', 'a': '1'}]
```

OR:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda d: d['b'] in x, dic['info'])),lst))

[[{'b': '1', 'a': 0}, {'b': '1', 'a': 0}], [{'b': '2', 'a': '1'}]]
```

Comment: I belive that it what I was looking for - no nested loops. I'll try this approach first.

Comment: @Always_hungry, sure, let me know how it did go

Comment: works great! could you explain please this code please if any(x == sub_d['b'] for x in lst)? my understanding: If any element x which is a dictionary element (sub_d) of key b is equal to any element in list lst?

Comment: It checks if `any` element `x` in list `lst` is equal to `sub_d['b']`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple list comprehension:

```
In [22]: dic = {'info': [{'a':0, 'b':'1'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'1'}]}

In [23]: lst = ['1']

In [25]: [sub_dict for sub_dict in dic['info'] if sub_dict['b'] == lst[0]]
Out[25]: [{'a': 0, 'b': '1'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '1'}]
```

Comment: I think the OP probably wants to provide a list of `b`s, so perhaps the test should be `sub_dict['b'] in lst`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `filter` approach:

```
filter(lambda x:x['b'] in list, dic['info'])
```

It will create a generator which you can materialize in a list:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x:x['b'] in list, dic['info']))
```

Mind I would however rename your `list` variable since you here override a reference to the `list` type.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic = {'info': [{'a':0, 'b':'1'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'1'}]}
d = defaultdict(list)
for each in dic['info']:
    d[each['b']].append(each)
```

out:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'1': [{'a': 0, 'b': '1'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '1'}],
             '3': [{'a': 0, 'b': '3'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '3'}]})
```

in:

```
d['1']
```

out:

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': '1'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '1'}]
```

Build an index dict to avoid iterate again.

Comment: you could add `d[list[0]]` to complete the OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

First go my simple loop and iteration way

**Input:**

```
>>> dic
{'info': [{'a': 0, 'b': '1'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '3'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '3'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '1'}]}
>>> l
['1']
```

**New List variable for result.**

```
>>> result = []
```

**Algo**

1. Iterate diction by `iteritems` method of dictionary.
2. Value of main dictionary is `list` data type. so again iterate list by for loop.
3. Check `b` key is present in sub dictionary and check its value is present in given list `l`.
4. If yes, then `append` to result list.

**code:**

```
>>> for k,v in dic.iteritems():
...     for i in v:
...         if "b" in i and i["b"] in l:
...             result.append(i)
...
```

**Output:**

```
>>> result
[{'a': 0, 'b': '1'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '1'}]
>>>
```

**Notes:**

1. Do not use `list` as variable name because `list` is reversed keyword for Python
2. Read basic things of dictionary and list which has properties.
3. Try to write code first.

Comment: 1) I used list so it looks clear - the above is only example 2) I read basic things 3) tried but wanted to avoid nested loops with which I started

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a list comprehension, or just do it using filter.

**list comprehension**

```
dict = {'info': [{'a':0, 'b':'1'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'1'}]}
lst = ['1']
result = [i for i in dict['info'] if i['b'] == lst[0]]

print result # [{'a': 0, 'b': '1'}, {'a': 0, 'b': '1'}]
```

**filter**

```
dict = {'info': [{'a':0, 'b':'1'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'3'},{'a':0, 'b':'1'}]}
list(filter(lambda i: i['b'] in lst, dic['info']))

# [{'b': '1', 'a': 0}, {'b': '1', 'a': 0}]
```